# Convert text to Uppercase while typing in text field with angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular reactive forms in order to validate forms. I need a way to automatically capitalize the text written in the input fields. In here I need a solution that will work with angular `formControl`. because I have tried out this problem with `ngModel` and it will generate the following warning

```
It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName.
```

Here is the form declaration

```
      this.rForm = this._FormBuilder.group({
      firstName: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      lastName: [null, Validators.compose([])],
      companyName: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      address: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      });
```

Here is an example of a form field that I have used in the HTML view.

```
                 <div class="has-default col-md-6 px-0">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                          <i class="material-icons">face</i>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="First Name"
                        formControlName="firstName"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="error-msg"
                      *ngIf="
                        !rForm.controls['firstName'].valid &&
                        rForm.controls['firstName'].touched
                      "
                    >
                      <small>First name <strong>required</strong> </small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template try this,

```
<div class="has-default col-md-6 px-0">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">
                          <i class="material-icons">face</i>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <input
                        (input)="changeTextToUppercase('firstName')"
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="First Name"
                        formControlName="firstName"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="error-msg"
                      *ngIf="
                        !rForm.controls['firstName'].valid &&
                        rForm.controls['firstName'].touched
                      "
                    >
                      <small>First name <strong>required</strong> </small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

And add this using the necessary form control name,

```
changeTextToUppercase(field) {
const obj = {};
obj[field] = this.rForm.controls[field].value.toUpperCase();
this.rForm.patchValue(obj);}
```